# Which Repository do I add to install Gnome 3 on Fedora 14

Tags: fedora, gnome3

I can't seem to find this anywhere. 
Also is there a list of repositories for third party software apart from livna? and is there a better package manager like Ubuntu's for Linux?

Comment: Don't try swapping package managers. They are stupid and oblivious to each other, so I'll bet your system will break almost instantly if you do. But if you *really* want to, do it in a LiveCD and see what happens ;)

Comment: What package manager are you currently using? I think the Fedora standard is `yum`, though it also has a port of `apt`, which may not be as well supported.

Comment: Im using yum, but the rpositories dont have as much software as Ubuntu. Somebody needs to tell the Fedora developers to look at the ubuntu software management system....I wanted to install PDFSAM and so other's...

Comment: Even if you manage to use Ubuntu repositories to install software on Fedora, you are really going to hose your system as mentioned by @Blender. Go get Ubuntu instead (if you really want such a huge repository), or go get Fedora 15... looks good during my initial poking.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you can't just use Fedora 15 which comes with Gnome3 already set up? Gnome 3 will not be available on Fedora 14 through official channels.

I looked for gnome3 packages on the [Fedora people repository list](http://repos.fedorapeople.org/) and didn't find a gnome3 repository (there is however, a gtk3 repository).

Besides fedorapeople, an important 3rd party repo is [rpmfusion](http://rpmfusion.org/)